# window.scroll not working with multiple scroll windows on the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, scroll, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to scroll using `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` in order to scroll to the bottom of the page in my email. I tried to implement this in both Outlook and Gmail, however, I receive the output of `undefined` and nothing happens.

The function works on other sites, so I'm guessing the issue could be that Outlook has two scrollable windows on the page I'm trying to scroll. How can I make it work and scroll the page on Gmail/Outlook?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. Gmail is not scrollable.
Have a look to the css properties, the main divs are in a fixed position.

Instead of doing a `window.scrollTo`, try to get the div which is scrollable in Gmail, and apply the scrollTo function on it instead of the window element :)

Comment: Thanks so much, that clarifies everything! I selected the div using ```document.getElementById("div.ReactVirtualized__Grid.ReactVirtualized__List._3j8nyZVfQVNuR").scrollTo(0, 2500)``` I also tried ```document.querySelector``` but it returns null. Could you advise what function should I use in order to get the scrollable div?